# Javascript/JQuery - Sort by split part of array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to sort an array by a split part of an array.

```
example_array = ["Zebra:Add","Pay:Cold","And:Vets","Jam:Back"]
```

I want to so it sorts it like this:

```
console.log(code here) // prints ["Zebra:Add","Jam:Back","Pay:Cold","And:Vets"]
```

Note: I want "Zebra:Add","Pay:Cold", etc to stay together. I just want it be sorted by the text after the ":".

Comment: Place in an anonymous compare function in the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method's parameter.

Comment: @guradio, nothing yet. I can't even think of a solution.

Comment: @Claof If you can't think of a solution, or a place to start, perhaps you need to take classes or use a tutorial. [This isn't the place to ask such low-quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309045/5743988).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment on the question:

> I can't even think of a solution

Break the problem into smaller pieces. You want to sort an array by a part of the strings in the array, so you need to figure out / look into

1. How to sort an array (you've done that, you've found the `sort` method)
2. How to isolate the part of the string you want to sort on
3. How to correctly compare strings for `Array#sort`
4. How to do #2 and #3 within the context of doing #1

Re #2, there are various ways to do that. You could find the `:` via `String#indexOf` and then use `substring` to get all characters after it. You could `split` the string on `:`, then use the second half (if you know there won't be more than one `:` in the string). Or you could use a regular expression to isolate everything after the first `:`.

For instance, `someString.match(/:.*$/)[0]` isolates all characters starting with the first `:`. (Including the `:` is harmless, but you could use `.substring(1)` if you don't want to include it.)

Re #3: `Array#sort` expects its callback to return a negative number if the first argument should come before the second, `0` if their order doesn't matter, or a positive number if the second should come before the first. `String#localeCompare` compares strings according to the current locale and returns exactly that information, so we want to use that.

Re #4: `Array#sort` accepts a callback function, so you could do all the string splitting and comparison in that callback. But since the callback will be called repeatedly, frequently with either the first or second argument being one that's already been checked before, for larger arrays doing it then may be inefficient. It may make more sense to do all the string splitting / isolation in advance, then do the sort, then get your desired result.

So:

The not-particularly-efficient way (which is fine for data sets like your small array) is to isolate the part you want to sort on within the sort callback:

```
var array = ["Zebra:Add","Pay:Cold","And:Vets","Jam:Back"];
array.sort(function(left, right) {
    return left.match(/:.*$/)[0].localeCompare(right.match(/:.*$/)[0]);
});
```

```js
var array = ["Zebra:Add","Pay:Cold","And:Vets","Jam:Back"];
array.sort(function(left, right) {
    return left.match(/:.*$/)[0].localeCompare(right.match(/:.*$/)[0]);
});
console.log(array);
```

With ES2015+ syntax:

```
const array = ["Zebra:Add","Pay:Cold","And:Vets","Jam:Back"];
array.sort((left, right) =>
    left.match(/:.*$/)[0].localeCompare(right.match(/:.*$/)[0])
);
```

```js
const array = ["Zebra:Add","Pay:Cold","And:Vets","Jam:Back"];
array.sort((left, right) =>
    left.match(/:.*$/)[0].localeCompare(right.match(/:.*$/)[0])
);
console.log(array);
```

If it's a massive array where doing those splits on every compare is problematic, you could map first, then sort, then unmap:

```
var array = /*...really big array...*/;
array =
  array.map(function(entry) { return {full: entry, key: entry.match(/:.*$/)[0]};})
       .sort(function(left, right) { return left.key.localeCompare(right.key); })
       .map(function(entry) { return entry.full; });
```

```js
var array = ["Zebra:Add","Pay:Cold","And:Vets","Jam:Back"];
array =
  array.map(function(entry) { return {full: entry, key: entry.match(/:.*$/)[0]};})
       .sort(function(left, right) { return left.key.localeCompare(right.key); })
       .map(function(entry) { return entry.full; });
console.log(array);
```

With ES2015+ syntax:

```
let array = /*...really big array...*/;
array =
  array.map(entry => ({full: entry, key: entry.match(/:.*$/)[0] }))
       .sort((left, right) => left.key.localeCompare(right.key))
       .map(entry => entry.full);
```

```js
let array = ["Zebra:Add","Pay:Cold","And:Vets","Jam:Back"];
array =
  array.map(entry => ({full: entry, key: entry.match(/:.*$/)[0] }))
       .sort((left, right) => left.key.localeCompare(right.key))
       .map(entry => entry.full);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly with my array that uses 160+ different strings!

Answer (score 0):

I like the simplicity of the previous answer, in comparison My approach is probably too wordy!  But here goes...

1.) take the original array and build a new sorting array from it, JSON array with each object having a text1 and text2 value... we'll sort on the text 2 value

2.) run a sort based on the text2 value

3.) empty the original array

4.) loop over the sorting array and re-populate the original array

heres a [fiddle example I threw together](https://jsfiddle.net/u05ebww2/)

```
// STARTING ARRAY.  WE WANT TO SORT BY THE TEXT AFTER THE COLON
example_array = ["Zebra:Add", "Pay:Cold", "And:Vets", "Jam:Back"];

// AN EMPTY ARRAY TO BUILD A JSON ARRAY FROM, THE SORT FROM THE DESIRED TEXT STRING
sorting_array = [];


// LOOP THROUGH THE ORIGINAL ARRAY AND PUSH A NEW OBJECT TO THE SORTING ARRAY
// EACH OBJECT CONTAINS A TEXT1 VALUE AND A TEXT2 VALUE
$.each(example_array, function(i, val){
   sorting_array.push({"text1": val.split(':')[0], "text2": val.split(':')[1]})
})

// SORT THE SORTING ARRAY BY THE TEXT2 VALUE
sorting_array.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.text2 < b.text2) return -1;
    if (b.text2 < a.text2) return 1;
    return 0;
});

// EMPTY OUR ORIGINAL ARRAY
example_array = [];

// FOR DEMO PURPOSES LETS DISPLAY EACH IN THE DOM IN A UL , 
// AND ALSO RE-POPULATE THE ORIGINAL ARRAY WITHT HE NEW ORDER
$.each(sorting_array, function(i, val){
   example_array.push(val.text1+':'+val.text2)
})

// TO SHOW THE NEW ORDER, LETS LOOP BACK OVER THE EXAMPLE_ARRAY
$.each(example_array, function(i, val){
    $('ul').append('<li>' + val+ '</li>');
})
```